# What is the symbolic meaning of the Mark of the Outsider in Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

I saw [this question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/dishonored/comments/5k5c2y/uncovering_the_meaning_of_the_outsider/), but the backstory of the mark doesn't get explained properly.

Is the outsider's mark explained in-universe? Does it have any symbolic meaning? What's its origin?

[image]

Comment: "it looks cool" I guess

Comment: I'm against closing this question, as I don't believe the reason used is that strict. I will edit the question to ask after an in-universe reason explicitly to settle. (Related meta discussion [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11319/why-was-a-mechanic-question-closed-for-game-design-and-development/))

Comment: Voting to leave open. Seems to be a lore question, and on-topic as per: [Should lore questions as an entire category be banned?](//meta.arqade.com/q/7696/4797) | [When is it appropriate to close a lore question as “not addressed directly through in-universe sources”?](//meta.arqade.com/q/7673/4797) | [Is “This question requires developer only knowledge” the same thing as developer intent?](//meta.arqade.com/q/9901/4797) | [Do we close plot-explanation questions if the answer is 'there is no explanation'?](//meta.arqade.com/q/8473/4797)

Comment: This also didn't need to be edited to restrict answers to cite in-universe sources only, as per the same meta posts I've linked above.

Comment: @galacticninja I don't see how those meta posts are relevant, but the question was edited anyway.

Comment: @Wrigglenite No one so far has explained why they're voting to close. It seemed to me that closing this is contrary to community consensus in the meta post, [When is it appropriate to close a lore question as “not addressed directly through in-universe sources”?](//meta.arqade.com/q/7673/4797) The other meta posts also touch on the same topic, including the meta post Joachim linked. All consensus on those meta posts are to leave questions like this opened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Originally, a [triskele](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskelion) design was explored, as it referenced the Circle of Life. The three interlocking forms represent the bearer's killer instinct and their ability to be unseen. The mark then evolved to become something **more tribal in nature and 'never before seen' as a reference to the Outsider's otherworldly nature**.
>
> <sup>[source](https://dishonored.fandom.com/wiki/Outsider%27s_Mark#Trivia) (redacted)</sup>

The Mark of the Outsider was designed by artist [Charles Bae](https://charlesbae.com/). Here are some of his concepts, visualizing the initial triskelion design, and the final rendition:

[image: Mark of the Outsider concepts and final rendition, by Charles Bae]
<sup>[source](https://charlesbae.com/)</sup>

On that same page, we can find more recent information about the Mark:

> In *Death of the Outsider*, **the Mark is revealed to be the Outsider's real name, written in a language only the dead can read**. If Billie Lurk decides to spare the Outsider, the spirit of Daud whispers the name to her (which can not be heard [here](https://youtu.be/AGyhWDopl_w?t=561)), and the Outsider is returned to the land of the living.
>  Whether the Mark itself has any power after this event is unknown.

Comment: So, "it looks cool"

Comment: The part about designing the mark is not an answer to the question, by the way.

Comment: Totally off-topic, but the marks on the right look like a [Mangekyō Sharingan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Mangekyō_Sharingan?file=Mangekyō_Sharingan_Itachi.svg) from the Naruto anime

Comment: @Wrigglenite If thoughtful design looks cool, then sure, one can belittle it that way. The extra part was added as just that: additional information, and relates directly to the initial triskelion design mentioned earlier in my post, giving insight, moreover, into what the designers thought would suit the otherworldly nature of the Outsider.

Comment: But it's not an in-universe explanation, so more than half of this post is effectively not an answer.

Comment: @Wrigglenite If you insist, I can take out the middle part (I thought of doing it right after posting it yesterday, but figured, like I mentioned, that a visualization of the process could prove insightful). I don't agree with what I assume is you saying that designing something is completely irrelevant to in-universe explanations: proper design has to take into account the limitations, possibilities, history, and style of that universe. How the designers of the game envision 'otherworldly' in relative terms is very much in-universe. Apart from that, it addresses the symbolism behind it.

Comment: @Wrigglenite OP's original edits (and intent) didn't restrict answers to cite in-universe sources only. Anyway, even if it just partly answers the question, it is still a valid answer.

Comment: Because the question was originally off-topic, and arguably still is. So sure, the question is "technically" not asking about out-of-universe sources, and the answer isn't "technically" worse by adding out-of-universe sources.

Comment: @Wrigglenite It was originally off-topic according to a very rigid interpretation of the closing reason, which has already been shown to not be the consensus. And if this is all technically correct, then what's your problem?

Comment: @Joachim Awesome answer, yo brought me more than I wanted. Just as curiosity and very off-topic, doy you think the triskelion has any realtionship with [rat king](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_king)? Or where do you suggest me to post this question?

Comment: @MetalFever Visually yes, but only because I presume rat kings are laid out like that so their entanglement becomes obvious. It is a good association, though, considering they signify a bad omen and are a symbol of the plague, that the presence of the rats in-game is a visual reflection of the amount of chaos, and that the vermin seem to be closely related to the supernatural.

Answer (score 3):

The Outsider's mark is actually The Outsider's name written in a text only the dead can read. This is revealed in the third game, Death of The Outsider, along with how the Outsider's name is said.